# How to make a set of div move along the screen. React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I was re-creating the animation shown in [Stripe](https://stripe.com/gb/about) website. Where a set of div's move together and it repeats infinitely.

I was trying to reproduce the same in my react app. But I'm stuck at how to implement the animation in it.

In [This](https://lokeshdhakar.com/dev-102-stripe.coms-scrolling-logo-bubbles/) tutorial they are doing the animation , but i could not find a way to implement the two classes in the js file in the above tutorial in my application.

Please tell me a solution to implement the animation, with or without the use of external react animation libraries.

[Link to my codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-brown-id8k7?file=/src/aboutPageAnimation.css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you gave: [My result looks like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-liskov-4vbfq?file=/src/AboutPageAnimation.js)